# why the session variable is empty?

Tags: php

I have been working is a website 
I have been dealing with a problem from a while, and now I know why it is happening, but not how to solve it. Please help!!

Step 1
In the first page, login page set the $_SESSION['user_id'] is stored the value that are fetch in database user id . it was working properly and also I print the session value in same page.and also navigate the next page.

Step 2
the next page is user home page, but in this page session variable is empty
This works perfectly most of the times,but in a few cases the session variable is empty in the next page, even when

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to call session_start(); either on the homepage, on  the login page or on both. You'll need to call it in every page you need it, to make the sessions variables available.

Comment: <?php session_start(); is used in both pages.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet? Without anything to look at it's kinda hard to help you.